# PartitionOffsetRequestInfo what does maxNumOffsets means?

Tags: apache-kafka

```
case class PartitionOffsetRequestInfo(time: Long, maxNumOffsets: Int)
```

Anyone know the means of macNumOffsets,ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Setting **maxNumOffset** to anything larger than 1 give us more message offsets before the given time

See : http://cfchou.github.io/blog/2015/04/23/a-closer-look-at-kafka-offsetrequest/

Comment: Got it and ty :)